# Объединить два формата дат по первому месяцу

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Итак, есть первый DF:

```
Year    FIRM    x1
2010    1   5
2011    1   5
2012    1   5
2008    2   5
2009    2   5
```

И есть второй DF:

```
Data    FIRM    x2
31.12.2009  1   4
31.01.2010  1   3
28.02.2010  1   2
31.03.2010  1   5
31.01.2011  1   4
28.02.2012  1   8
31.12.2007  2   9
31.01.2008  2   8
28.02.2008  2   7
31.03.2009  2   8
```

Нужно объединить год со значением первого месяца (т.е. 31.01.XXXX), если совпадений нет по первому месяцу, не берем в выборку. На выходе должно получиться нечто такое:

```
Year    FIRM    x1  x2
2010    1   5   3
2011    1   5   4
2008    2   5   8
```

И если нетрудно, возможность для сопоставления с любым из месяцев (универсальную формулу)

Comment: Нужно объединить не только по году, но и по столбцу "FIRM"?

Comment: Да, все верно, по обоим

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение похожее на [решение от @Andrey](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/961256/211923), но немного короче:

```
res = (d1.merge(d2.assign(Year=d2['Data'].dt.year)
                  .query("Data.dt.month == 1")
                  .drop('Data',1),
                on=['FIRM','Year']))
```

---

```
In [10]: res
Out[10]:
   Year  FIRM  x1  x2
0  2010     1   5   3
1  2011     1   5   4
2  2008     2   5   8
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать сначала отфильтровать второй df, оставив только строки со значениями за первый месяц:

```
filtered = df2[df2.Data.dt.month == 1]
```

Получим:

```
          Data   FIRM   x2
1   2010-01-31      1    3
4   2011-01-31      1    4
7   2008-01-31      2    8
```

И дальше с помощью `merge()` объединить этот датафрейм с первым по годам и столбцу "FIRM":

```
result = (filtered.merge(df1, left_on=['FIRM', filtered.Data.dt.year],
                              right_on=['FIRM', 'Year'])
                  .drop('Data', axis=1)
                  .reindex(columns=['Year', 'FIRM', 'x1', 'x2']))
```

Результат:

```
    Year    FIRM    x1  x2
0   2010       1     5   3
1   2011       1     5   4
2   2008       2     5   8
```